# MATLAB: A loop to check for existing variables

Tags: matlab, loops

I am writing a script that runs a picture or a lego and outputs its size, shape, and color. The way we wrote the script, each time we use a new picture of a different lego, we must clear the workspace of variables. We must catalog each lego we run through the script. We have the variables going to a .mat file, but cannot seem to save more than one at a time as each time we run the script, the variables saved are replaced with the new values. I've decided the best way to go about this is to run the .mat through a loop to check for existing values and in the case there is one, saving the values in the row beneath the existing. Any help would be much appreciated as I am new to MATLAB and most especially loops. I asked a question regarding this several days ago, but have decided to approach the problem in a new way due to a few barriers. Many thanks.

EDIT:

```
    if  length > 40 & length < 70
    y_length = 'Two'
    area_length = 2
elseif length > 70 & length < 90
    y_length = 'Three'
    area_length = 3
elseif length > 70 & length < 145
        y_length = 'Four'
        area_length = 4
elseif length > 150 & length < 200
    y_length = 'Six'
    area_length = 6
elseif length < 40
    y_length = 'One'
    area_length = 1
elseif length > 200
    y_length = 'Eight'
    area_length = 8
end

    if strcmp(x_length,y_length)
    shape = 'Square'
else
    shape = 'Rectangle'
end

    size = area_width * area_length ;

    %%%%%% make sure smaller dimension always first %%%%%
% width = smaller length 
% length = longer length

    Cell = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length};

    % for iterations 1:block_count
%     if Final = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length}
disp(Cell)     
 SaveData = {sprintf('%s, %d, %s, %s, %s', Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length)};
% load('Data.mat');
% 

    data = [data; SaveData];
save('Data.mat', 'SaveData'); 
if  length > 40 & length < 70
        y_length = 'Two'
        area_length = 2
    elseif length > 70 & length < 90
        y_length = 'Three'
        area_length = 3
    elseif length > 70 & length < 145
            y_length = 'Four'
            area_length = 4
    elseif length > 150 & length < 200
        y_length = 'Six'
        area_length = 6
    elseif length < 40
        y_length = 'One'
        area_length = 1
    elseif length > 200
        y_length = 'Eight'
        area_length = 8
    end

    if strcmp(x_length,y_length)
    shape = 'Square'
else
    shape = 'Rectangle'
end

    size = area_width * area_length ;

    %%%%%% make sure smaller dimension always first %%%%%
% width = smaller length 
% length = longer length

    Cell = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length};

    % for iterations 1:block_count
%     if Final = {Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length}
disp(Cell)     
 SaveData = {sprintf('%s, %d, %s, %s, %s', Color, size, shape, x_length, y_length)};
% load('Data.mat');
% 

    data = [data; SaveData];
save('Data.mat', 'SaveData');  



                                                                                                   This is the  bottom portion of the script, hopefully enough to give you an idea. Would it be better to change the name of Cell each time it is saved in the .mat file and -append it? Perhaps a loop to recognize the presence of a value in the existing Data.mat and placing it a row below it?
```

Comment: Hi, I guess that since you are new to loops, that means that you are new to programming as well. I am not 100% on what you want in the question, but if I have not misunderstood completely, I think there are other ways to do this. Just to be able to give a better answer, could you explin the following: what is a lego and what is the difference between a lego and a picture? Is it supposed to be a picture of lego piece and is the sentence supposed to be **"... runs a picture of a lego piece and..."**. Further, it would be easier to understand if you are able to upload a short code sample.

Comment: A lego is a toy building block. The picture is of this toy block. All pictures are taken keeping all variables the same. Essentially the script finds the difference between the white background and the picture and outputs variables: size, shape, color. We put these variables as a string in a single cell with variable name Cell. We are essentially trying to save each Cell value for each time we run this script.

Comment: I have added the bottom portion of the script as an edit to the original post. Would it be any better to -append and create a loop to rename the Cell variable each time? A big problem we are having is the Cell value overwriting the value stored in Data.mat. Changing the variable name each time would add the new value to the Data.mat using Save( and -append, correct?

Comment: Since you have a lot of copy-pasted code I would say that you would gain on using a function. That can also be used to limit scope (so that you do not have to clear workspace before you are done). A lot of copy-pasted code normally means it is possible to do better. Further, I cannot really see why you are saving to file and loading all the time. Do you want to save the different variables `SaveData` to a number of different files? If not I would recommend you to use a struct array. Then each element can have two fields. `name` (or id maybe) and `data`. Further, there are cell arrays as well.

Comment: Further, I see no `clear` in the code so that part needs to be better explained to fit into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You're still going at this the hard way. If you have a list of `n` pictures you need to process, add a loop like so:

```
for k = 1:n
   %// Process picture k, generating newCell
   %// then append newCell to the end of allCells array
   allCells(k,:) = newCell;
end
```

Now, if you still need to save these to a file, you can save just `allCells` and get all of your data at once.

If you don't have a list of images beforehand, you can still accomplish your goal by loading the array, adding a new row and then saving it again:

```
load('allCells.mat');
%// Process picture, generating newCell
allCells(end+1,:) = newCell;
save('allCells.mat',allCells);
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to save different files for the different pieces, `i.e.` one file per itertion of the loop.

Something like:

```
for k = 1:n

    % Do your processing here.
    % Say that the interesting variables are A, B and C.

    filename = ['Data_' num2str(k, '%06i') '.mat'];
    save(filename, 'A', 'B', 'C');

end
```

With this approach the folder in which you run the script will contain `n` datafiles called `Data_000000.mat`, `Data_000001.mat`, ... corresponding to the `n` iterations.

If you prefer to have a single mat file, then it's generally preferable to save it only once after the loop. For instance:

```
for k = 1:n

    % Do your processing here.
    % Say that the interesting variables are A, B and C.

    A(k) = ....;        
    B(k) = ....;
    C(k) = ....;

end

% Save the results
save('Data.mat', 'A', 'B', 'C');
```

Best,

Comment: This seems kind of messy, since the problem seems to be a scope issue. Normally `functions` are used for separating scopes, but I think that OP is not aware of functions yet. Normally saving to file is not what is recommended for scope related issues. Further, the second solution might not work since OP states that they need to **"clear workspace"**.

Comment: @patrik It's hard to know what's in an OP's mind, and my feeling is that it's not a scope problem after all. You are right on the second method, though it depends on how the OP uses `clear`. Hard to tell with such few information.